# Default ZIP icon is not loading for the Sitecore Media Item

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library

In Sitecore 9 when we are uploading the zip file in Sitecore Media library. Icon is loading from the template "/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Zip" instead of taking from the temp folder. Please let me know if you have any solution for this. It is happening in Azure Paas. [image]

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Do you have any customized icon for the media type "zip".? I mean any change in Sitecore.config file's <mediaType name="Zip file" extensions="zip"> node.?

Comment: Got a solution for this. Earlier temp folder path was incorrect in the config.